# Chrome Apps chrome.networking.onc API not available for kiosk apps

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

## Background

I have a Chrome Kiosk App where i would like to use the `chrome.networking.onc` API to let my users change WiFi networks.

## My issue

There is no `chrome.networking.onc` API available to the app neither in the app background script or the app window while running in a kiosk session.

## What I've tried

According to the `chrome.networking.onc` documentation it should be available to apps while in kiosk mode.

I've added `networking.onc` to my `permissions` in my app manifest.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/networking_onc

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions

The kiosk app is force installed to the users Chromebooks using a G Suite Chrome device management policy.

## Code example

#### app/manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Kiosk networking.onc",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["networking.onc"],
  "kiosk_enabled": true,
  "kiosk_only": true,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

#### app/background.js

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  // send a list of available chrome APIs to the app window to be displayed
  chrome.app.window.create(`window/main.html?chrome=${Object.keys(chrome).join(",")}&kiosk=${launchData.isKioskSession}`);
});
```

#### app/window/main.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Chrome app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <h1>Background <code>chrome</code> object properties</h1>
      <div id="background"></div>
    </p>

    <p>
      <h1>App window <code>chrome</code> object properties</h1>
      <div id="window"></div>
    </p>

    <button id="exit">window.close()</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### app/window/main.js

```js
// display the available Chrome APIs in the background script
document.getElementById("background").innerText = window.location.search;

// display all the available Chrome APIs (accessible from the app window).
document.getElementById("window").innerText = Object.keys(chrome).join(",");

document.getElementById("exit").onclick = () => window.close()
```

### Output while in a kiosk session (Chrome OS 77.0.3865.105)

In the image below `networking` cannot be found among the available APIs and if i try to access `networking.onc` i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onc' of undefined`

[image: Chrome kiosk session result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by a bug in Chrome OS.

I've reported the issue in the Chromium issue tracker here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012629